# Detect 3rd party extension from client

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This has been a bit hard to find, given Chrome has changed its API a lot so have found outdated suggestions. And what's not outdated is from the POV of writing an extension

Our js app is having trouble when some users have a specific chrome Extension installed. We want to warn users of potential issues if it sees that extension is present in the users browser.

This extension loads a single content-script and runs in the background. It doesn't have an open connection, exposure variables to the clients `window` or anything advanced.

Is there a way the client can ping or check for this script?

For instance, I tried using `fetch` of the chrome-extension:// manifest - same via a  `script` tag loading the extensions `main.js` but those don't work, chrome complaining it can't load the asset (presumably a permissions issue)

Is it even possible?

Comment: Only stuff listed in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) can be accessed by a web page. Your only option is to see what extension does in its source code and try to detect its presence by some artifact it adds or removes like a request header or DOM element/style.

Comment: Right. Looks like there are no web accessable resources available so yeah, that leaves trying to spy manipulations to the DOM. That ain't foolproof, so hmmm. There are 3 named functions but they don't appear on the client scope . I guess that's intentional for extension scripts as they don't share the same `winkow` namespace.